# Dependence of saturation current in photoelectric tube on the time taken by the electron to reach the opposite plate?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

The kinetic energy of an electron in a photoelectric tube increases with increase in the applied voltage across the plates of the tube, thus the velocity of the electrons also increases. Accordingly the time taken by the electron to reach the opposite plate should be less and so the current in the external circuit should increase as $i=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and so current is inversely proportional to time.But this is not the case as the value of saturation current remains the same.Why is the value not depending on the time taken by the electron to reach the opposite plate?

Comment: Vacuum or gas-filled?

Comment: Vacuum.But I would also like to know the difference in the result if the vacuum was replaces with air.

Comment: Beyond saturation the tube generates a constant amount of charge per photon. Why would the total current increase if the charge doesn't? At most the waveform generated gets a little faster, which makes the peak current increase. Are you measuring the time resolved pulses or just the average current? The average can't change because the charge is always the same.

Comment: I am measuring the average current.Although the number of charge does not increase but the speed of the electron increases so the rate of flow of electrons should also  increase and as current is the rate if flow of charge so the current should increase

Comment: Yep, that increases the peak current, but not the average. You are not measuring the peak and the average stays the same. Get yourself a really fast oscilloscope and look at the individual pulses.

Comment: Why doesent the average current change? It is also inversely proportional to time.

Comment: The average current is the average number of pulses per time unit (the pulse rate) times the charge per pulse. Both are constant past the saturation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current in any circuit is given by i= dq/dt. q being the charge of the carriers not dp/dt. Increasing the voltage will only increase the kinetic energy of the electrons coming out but not the current because the number of electrons available is the same(unless you are varying the intensity of the light which is creating the effect).

But if their is air, it should resist the electron flow a little. Hence you might see a voltage dependence. But that possibly wouldn't be ohmic.

Comment: Current depends on charge as well as time.Although the charge remains the same but the time taken by the electrons to flow decreases so the rate of flow of electrons should increase thereby increasing the current.

Comment: Please tell me where i am getting it wrong.

Comment: Yes it depends on time. But please understand that the travelling time is not important. The question is "How much charge is reaching anode per unit TIME?" Got it?

Comment: Lets take an example suppose 10 electrons are emmited from emitter plate and they reach the anode in 5 secs so the current will be 10/5=2 and let another setup emit 10 electrons which take 10 secs to reach the anode, the average current will be then 10/10=1.So how is it the same?

Comment: No. If 10 electrons are emitted and they reach the anode at the same time the current would be a sharp spike and then zero. It has nothing to do with time of flight. it's same in both cases.

Comment: The electrons are not reaching at the same time. In the 1st case assume that 2 electrons are reaching the plate per sec and in 2nd case one electron is reaching per sec on an average.

Comment: How many electrons will reach the plate at same time depends on how many got struck out from metal at the same time(because all of them has almostsame velocity). That number of electron depends on the intensity of light not the potential.

Comment: Since by increasing the potential the electric Field between the plates increases and so the force acting on the electrons also increase and so the electron's velocity depends on the acceleration and so it depends on the volatage applied.

Comment: What I'm emphasizing repeatedly is that speed of those electrons would increase, but it does not effect how many reaches the anode per second. Does it? Because the speed of each electron would increase. How can that change the no of electron reachin per unit time?

Comment: Think of it this way.. Somebody is throwing balls and you are catching them. Now if he is throwing 10 balls/ sec you will recieve 10 balls/sec, irrespective of which speed they are travelling in mid-air.

Comment: The voltage(until it is of correct sign) can only change the velocity in mid-air. The no of balls is decided by intensity.

Answer (score 1):

The saturation current is the same because the RATE of charge flow per unit time is the same. Shorter time, smaller charge flow.
The charge is not fixed. The amount of photoelectrons emitted is maxed. So all that are emitted are being collected

Answer (score 0):

The rate determining step is not the time taken by the electrons to reach the opposite plate. What I mean is, the electrons that are emitted reach the opposite plate almost instantaneously. Assuming constant electric field between plates $E$ and charge of electron $e$ and mass $m$  and distance between plates $x$. Time $t$ taken to reach the opposite plates for an electron starting from rest is $$T=\frac{\sqrt {2xm}}{\sqrt{eE}}$$
The $m/e$ ratio for electrons is so small that we can assume $T=0$. Thus even if  the $E$ field is increased ,after a certain limit, the effect would be negligible. The crucial step that determines the current is the number of electrons that are emitted which is solely dependent on intensity of light.