# Is there a relationship between kinetic energy of emitted electron and photoelectric current?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I know that photoelectric current is dependent upon intensity of incident light. But it should also be dependent upon kinetic energy of emitted electron because mathematically $I=Q/T$. So if kinetic energy is more then time becomes less. Please help and let me know if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: But are the two times you are talking about the same?

Comment: possible duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207729/dependence-of-saturation-current-in-photoelectric-tube-on-the-time-taken-by-the/207732#207732

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong.

The current is limited by the number of electrons per second emitted from the metal surface. Once a steady state current is established the number of electrons per second received by the collecting electrode is the same as the number emitted per second from the metal surface and the speed the electrons travel from the metal to the electrode makes no difference.

However the speed of the electrons will affect the time the current takes to settle to a constant value after the light is turned on. When you trun the light on there is a delay before the collecting electrode starts registering a current, and the faster the electrons move the shorter this delay. Likewise the decay rate of the current when the light is turned off also depends on the electron speed.